# Is there a way to determine what exact solidity version will be used?

Tags: solidity, remix

Imagine a non specific pragma statement
`pragma solidity >=0.8.7 <0.8.12;`

Is there an algorithm to determine if there the solidity version? Like maybe low to high?

Or is it platform specific (If that is something not sure tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement essentially means the code will compile with any version of the solidity compiler in that range. The exact version of solidity used depends on the version used by the compiler software you use, usually defined in your hardhat or truffle config files. In the case of remix, it will be which ever version of the compiler you select from the dropdown menu during compilation.